# Indesign script to replace paragraph style

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, paragraph-styles, javascript

I am using ID CC 2014 on a Mac and there's a huge file with several hundred pages where I need to delete a certain paragraph style replacing it with another. Say there's a para style called "style-1". When I delete it from the para styles panel, it asks me to provide another style to take its place for pieces of text currently styled as "style-1". Here, I add, say, "style-2" to take its place. Is there any way to automate the process using a script? I tried studying the `FindTextPreference` JS class but it doesn't seem to have the properties we might need in this case. Any tips?

Comment: I didn't quite understand. How much more automatic can you get than the delete method?  ...the delete method, that automatically replaces all occurences of one paragraph style with another...

Comment: When you delete a paragraph style you also need to reassign a new style to take its place. I am looking to automate the process of deleting style-1 and then assigning the text (that was until now styled as style-1) to style-2. So yeah that's at least 4 mouse-clicks reduced right there. Besides, in my workflow, I'm gonna have to repeat this process for a whole bunch of styles so yeah the automation is justified. Let's focus on "how" rather than "why." Thanks.

Comment: OP's quite often want one thing but actually need something else. When someone asks about automating a seemingly automatic function in a software, I'd rather figure out why, than to just blindly do as master says.

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out and posted my solution for others. Thanks for your time. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured out the answer myself and am posting it here for the benefit of others. The trick is to call the `remove` method of the `ParagraphStyle` class (more accurately, the paragraph style being removed). The syntax is:

```
Old_Style.remove(New_Style);
```

In this syntax, the `New_Style` argument is optional. Thus, for my example, the correct code would be:

var  old = app.activeDocument.paragraphStyles.itemByName("style-1");
var  new = app.activeDocument.paragraphStyles.itemByName("style-2");
old.remove(new);

More details on the `ParagraphStyle` class can be found at http://jongware.mit.edu/idcsjs5.5/pc_ParagraphStyle.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script.

```
    var myDoc = app.activeDocument;  

try {
myDoc.paragraphStyles.item("Old Still").remove("New Still");
} catch(e) {}
```

İf you want to replace more than one style just duplicate this code and change style names.

```
try {
    myDoc.paragraphStyles.item("Old Still").remove("New Still");
    } catch(e) {}
```

Comment: This solution is already included in the accepted answer, please don't just repeat information. There's plenty of unanswered questions that could benefit from your time.

Comment: Well, there is additional feature in the code I wrote. İf paragraph style doesn't exist in documents,  script will give error and stop working. İn my version script will ignore any error and try to replace existing paragraph styles.